# How to find position of HTML elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to *connect two points with a **line** while moving one of them*. I'm really lost in finding the real **x, y** position of anything on a document... I've read about how paddings, element sizes and all these things can mess up this process, but none of the tutorials or example codes worked. I would really appreciate if you could give my code a look and give a solution/url to some kind of tutorial or just a basic startingpoint.
Thanks in advance!

```js
var node = document.querySelector("#node");
var startNode = document.querySelector("#startnode");
var container = document.querySelector("#container");

container.addEventListener("click", SetNodePosition, false);

function SetNodePosition(e) {

  startX = getPosition(startNode).x;
  startY = getPosition(startNode).y;

  nodeX = getPosition(node).x;
  nodeY = getPosition(node).y;

  console.log("StartNode: " + startX + " - " + startY);
  console.log("Node: " + nodeX + " - " + nodeY)

  var translate3dValue = "translate3d(" + nodeX + "px," + nodeY + "px, 0)";
  node.style.transform = translate3dValue;

  if(typeof(document.getElementById("line1")) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById("line1") != null){
      updateLine(startX, nodeX, startY, nodeY, "line1");
  }
  else{
      createLine(startX, nodeX, startY, nodeY, "line1");
  }
}

function getPosition(element) {

  //FIND AND RETURN ELEMENT X, Y POSITION
  
}

function createLine(x1, x2, y1, y2, lineId) {
    distance = Math.sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + ((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));

    xMid = (x1+x2)/2;
    yMid = (y1+y2)/2;

    slopeInRadian = Math.atan2(y1-y2, x1-x2);
    slopeInDegrees = (slopeInRadian*180)/Math.PI;

    var line = document.createElement("div");
    line.setAttribute("id", lineId);
    line.style.height = "2px"
    line.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    line.style.width = distance + "px";
    line.style.top = yMid + "px";
    line.style.left = (xMid - (distance/2)) + "px";
    line.style.transform = "rotate(" + slopeInDegrees + "deg)";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(line);

    console.log()
}

function updateLine(x1, x2, y1, y2, lineId) {
    distance = Math.sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + ((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));

    xMid = (x1+x2)/2;
    yMid = (y1+y2)/2;

    slopeInRadian = Math.atan2(y1-y2, x1-x2);
    slopeInDegrees = (slopeInRadian*180)/Math.PI;

    var line = document.getElementById(lineId)
    line.style.width = distance + "px";
    line.style.top = yMid + "px";
    line.style.left = (xMid - (distance/2)) + "px";
    line.style.transform = "rotate(" + slopeInDegrees + "deg)";
}
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
#startnode {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;

    transform: translate3d(200px, 25px, 0);
}
#node {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: move;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;

    transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, 0);
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div id="container">

        <div id="startnode"></div>
        <div id="node"></div>
      
    </div>
    
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() will give the position of the element, all four corners of it

Comment: jQuery offset();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getBoundingClientRect` function will give you the x and y position of the element

```
function getPosition(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { x: rect.left, y: rect.top };
}
```

In `SetNodePosition` function, instead of calling this function two times for each html element, call it once for each element as shown below

```
function SetNodePosition(e) {

  let { x: startNodeX, y:startNodeY } = getPosition(startNode);
  startX = startNodeX;
  startY = startNodeY;

  console.log("StartNode: " + startX + " - " + startY);

  ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great! Although I realised, this only solves half of my problems... I asked the wrong question basically. 
I'll make another post I guess, but just in case: the problem would be with finding the mouse location, as if I'm right, you can't use getBoundingClientRect() for a mouse location. Knowing the mouse pos would be neccesary for moving one of the points.

Comment: You can attach any mouse event on a container. To find the x and y position of mouse pointer when that event fires, use `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

So, like you asked; with a canvas you can perform a lot of functions and a variety of libraries are available which can extend the functionality. So if you want to get the position of the box when you click on it, you can get that value.

Basically what I am doing is getting the mouse position all the time via canvas function and when you click, that position is written to a div

```js
function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.font = '18pt Calibri';
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
      }
      
function mousePosition(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }
      
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = mousePosition(canvas, evt);
        var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
        writeMessage(canvas, message);
      }, false);
      
      canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = mousePosition(canvas, evt);
        var message = 'Position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
        document.getElementById('click').innerHTML = message;
      }, false);
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #AAAAAA;" id="click">Not Clicked Yet
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```